# Integrating $\int \frac{e^{\cos x} \cdot \sin x}{2 + \cos x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

In an exam this morning, I was given a definite integral that can supposedly be solved using substitution:

$$\int_a^b \frac{e^{\cos x} \cdot \sin x}{2 + \cos x} dx$$

(I forget what the limits were, but that's irrelevant now.)

The farthest I got was $u = \cos x$ or $u = \cos x + 2$, and thus $du=-\sin xdx$ and the integral becomes

$$-\int \frac{e^{u}}{2 + u} du$$

or

$$-\int \frac{e^{u - 2}}{u} du$$

However, I couldn't figure out how to integrate either of those, and no other substitutions jumped out at me.

So: out of curiosity, how can I solve this integral?

$$\int \frac{e^{\cos x} \cdot \sin x}{2 + \cos x} dx$$

Based on what we've covered in the course so far, it should only need basic antiderivative rules
($\int a^x dx = \frac{a^{x+1}}{x+1}$, $\int \frac 1 x dx = \ln|x|$, etc.), inverse sine and tangent ($\int \frac 1 {\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}} dx = \sin^{-1} (\frac x a)$, etc.), and/or substitution.

Comment: $dx$ is missing

Comment: See [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Comment: @Lucian unless my professor expects us to know stuff he hasn't taught us yet,  the exponential integral shouldn't need to be used.

Comment: There's no 'easy' answer to that integral, i.e the answer cannot only be expressed in terms of elementary functions (like $x^n$, $a^x$, $\ln x$, $\sin x$, $\arccos x$, ...). So if exponential integral isn't allowed, then that problem cannot be solved.

Comment: Nonelementary function...; it may very well that the question was mis-given in your test.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Ask your teacher for the answer and PLEASE share it with us. :), Hope you did pass your exam...

Comment: I have a hunch on it. Maybe you or your professor just got the question wrong. For example, both $\int \frac{e^{\cos x} \cdot \cos^2 (x)}{1 + \cos x} dx$ and $\int \frac{e^{\cos x} \cdot \sin^2 (x)}{2 + \cos x} dx$ have close form. (Though the latter is much more ugly)

Comment: no closed form will be exspected